# Xcode 4 crash when opening project cloned or pulled from git repository

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4, crash, clone

After pushing my project to remote and pulling it back to the other machine I get this crash when I try to open it in Xcode 4.3.2:

[image]

Project package contents:
[image]

This happens every time for this project.
I have tried to resolve it by cleaning proect package content form *pbxuser* and *mode1v3* files but with no effect.
What could be the reason of that and how to repair it? Is there any **xcodeproj** repair tool or analyzer?
May it be fault of my gitattributes file?:

```
*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge
```

I do not use  .gitignore on tis project (project is quite small).

Comment: Xcode 4.5 is pre-release software and subject to NDA.  Ask this question in the devtools forum at Apple: https://devforums.apple.com/community/mac/pre/devtools

Comment: It happens on 4.3 the screenshot was one of many tries. I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this in the past ... start Xcode on a known good project, close all windows, then go via File->Open to locate the .xcodeproj file, and select your new project. That solved it for me at the time, hope it will for you : had me stumped for a bit.